# Basic real analysis - Relative openness theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to get the intuition behind the following basic real analysis theorem, with $X$ being some metric space. This is thm 2.30 from Rudin.

A set $E \subseteq Y \subseteq X$ is open relative to $Y$ iff there exists open set $G \subseteq X$ such that $E = G \cap Y$.

What I specifically do not understand is what is the point of using $G$. With the concrete example of $E = (0,1)$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$, and $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, we can choose some disk as $G$ but when intersected with $Y$, we simply "cancel out" the disk part to get an open interval - so why care about a subset of $X$ when it gets cancelled?

Is there an example where this $G$ matters?

Comment: take $E=[0,1[$ to sense what are the open relative in it

Comment: The subspace topology on $Y$ is precisely the set of all $G\cap Y$ for open sets $G$ of $X$.

Comment: Try, instead, to define an open set $E$ relative to $Y$ in a pointwise manner:  what condition would you want at each point $x\in E$ for it to be an "interior" point relative to the set $Y$?  Then decide if your condition is equivalent to this one.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is why isn't the subspace topology on $ Y \subseteq X$ simply the open sets of $X$ which are also contained in $Y$ , then consider when Y is not open. Well the collection of open sets relative to X contained in Y cannot be a topology for Y, since the union of all such sets must equal Y and is open in X. Contradiction to Y being not open in X.

It turns out that the collection of all $E$ s.t. $E = G \cap Y$ for some open set $G$ in X is the smallest topology for $Y$ which includes all open sets of X which are contained in Y.